# Updating Userform (based on excel values) when Excel sheet is updated via another person

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Userform that interacts with a sheet in excel, the Userform when activated pulls from the appropriate cells, gets updated and when "Saved", will update all the cells that have been changed.

As the sheet will be shared and multiple changes could happen at once, I'd like a way of detecting when a "Save" has been committed to the sheet, and inform / update any users with the Userform Open. I can worry about conflicting updates later, at the moment I'd just like this basic feature.

Is there a good way to achieve this?

Comment: I have a basic idea of utilizing the Worksheet_Update() command to inform the user of changes to the worksheet, however this will inform the user that "Changes have been made" when they save their own changes.